# custom uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i building an chat app and i have a little problem, build cellforrowatindexpath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UserCell";


UserCell *cell = (UserCell *)
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (nil == cell) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserCell" 
                                                             owner:nil 
                                                           options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (UserCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

NSString *nameValue = [self.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *statusValue = [self.usersStatus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.name.text = nameValue;
cell.status.text = statusValue;


return cell;
```

}

and in every cell i have a label what is hidden,and in:

```
-(void)chatHandlerNewMsg:(ChatHandler*)chat withInt:(NSString*)userId{
NSInteger tmp = [self.usersID indexOfObject:userId];
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tmp inSection:0];
UserCell *cell = (UserCell*)[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
[cell.newMsg setHidden:NO];
[self.table reloadData];
```

}

i check for new msg and if so i bring the uilabel from hidden to shown.

the problem is that the table view show this uilabel(that it is hidden by default) in other cells in the table view and not only in the specific one that we choose in :

```
UserCell *cell = (UserCell*)[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you dequeue a cell you need to manually reset any state that a previous row may have set.

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell) {
    //Reset cell state (make label hidden)
}
else
{
    //Create new cell and configure (hide labels)
}

//Set any common attributes here (title)

return cell;
```